# using Windows update tool to update my sharepoint 2013 server, will show many unnecessary updates

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, administration, configuration, windows-server-2008-r2

I have the following:-

- Windows server 2008 R2.
- SharePoint enterprise server 2013 sp1.
- SharePoint Designer

Today I ran the windows update and it showed that there are 28 important update with total size of 1.1 GB. When I view the details for the updates I found updates for SharePoint foundation, outlook, word, lync, office 2013 as follow:-

[image]

**First question.** Should I install all the updates or since I am using SharePoint enterprise and I do not to install updates for :-

- SharePoint foundation,
- outlook,
- word,
- lync,
- office 2013

… so should I ignore these updates and only install SharePoint enterprise 2013 related updates and security updates for windows server 2008 r2.?

**Second question.** Generally speaking will windows update  only show the updates required for my server? Or it simply display any new updates regardless if i need them or not. For example inside my live SharePoint serve I do not have outlook or lync  installed , so why it showed me an update for outlook and another one for lync?. and if I install these updates what will basically happen? Will the update consume a disk space, or it will not be installed ?

Thanks

Comment: do you have Office Installed on that server?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Yes but i only have SharePoint Designer 2013 installed , i do not have lync , word or outlook installed in the server.. as i got updates for these in addition to getting updates for SharePoint foundation , while i have SharePoint server..

Comment: so should i trust windows update tool and install all the update it mentioned?

Comment: It looks like going forward only Security updates will be available through Windows Updates: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2015/03/02/sharepoint-cus-and-windows-update-important-update.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As per my experience, it is really not good practice to update the SharePoint from Windows Update tool.

Why, If you enable the Automatic Windows Update then it will deploy all updates(Including the SharePoint) as per the schedule set. sometimes you know and some time you don't.

- When you apply CU to SharePoint you need to run Config wizard otherwise farm will not be stable
- No testing performed in advance because you don't know about update applied...
- As Per MSFT recommend don't apply CU Unless you need it.
- As Per MSFT you have to perform full testing before applying to prod
- You have to schedule Down Time for the CU patching but if automatic applied then you cant control.

In NutShell, Turn Off Windows Update....Apply the updates which you need and perform full testing before hand.
http://www.akspug.org/Blog/Post/47/Be-Careful--October-2013-Office---SharePoint-patches-are-on-Windows-Update

Comment: Yes this what i currently follow. I turnoff windows automatic update. so windows will inform me about any updates , but will not download or install them unless i conform this. so on our testing server i install the updates first, then i do a full test , and if every thing went well, i install the updates on the live server. but my original question is about if i need to install all the updates mentioned by the windows update tool or not? and on MSDN link (i can not remember it), they mentioned that it is better to update SP server using windows update tool rather than applying the CU manually